# Loading a package when a macro is used

Tags: macros, xetex, packages

So, I have a big preamble that I use for all my homeworks. For some homeworks, I have to typeset code, for which I typically use the `minted` package. I have a little macro `\pyminted[1]` that stores the options that I like, so I can just type `\pyminted{code.py}` and be done.

The thing is that `minted` makes some auxiliary files/folders when loaded with `\usepackage`, regardless of whether it is actually typesetting code. I'd rather not have these files everywhere, so I was thinking of adding the `\usepackage{minted}` to my `\pyminted` macro. The problem is of course that `\usepackage` can only be used in the preamble.

Is there a way to conditionally load a package only when it will be used inside a macro that calls it?

Comment: Maybe you want check the `cache` and `cachedir` options (of `minted` package). If you disable `cache` the `minted`-directory will not create (but the re-compilation will slow). I think the best solution is `cachedir`: set it to a dedicated directory (for example `/home/windolf/.minted-cache/`).

Comment: it's generally advisable to not have a big preamble, most documents should only load the packages they actually used. Also minted requires `-shell-escape` it's definitely not recommended to routinely use `-shell-escape`

Comment: You can't load a package past `\begin{document}`. Well, in some cases you *could*, but it's definitely bad practice.